# Show that $\ell _2 ^2$ is not isometric to $\ell _2 ^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> **Show that $\ell _2 ^2$ is not isometric to $\ell _2 ^\infty$.**

I have seen similar questions but none of them were between those two spaces. The definition of the two isometric spaces is as follows:

> A metric space $X$ is isometric to a metric space $Y$ if there is a bijection $f$ between $X$ and $Y$ such that $d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$.

I know that for every $x \in \ell_2^2$ the norm is $$||x||_2=\left(\sum_{i=0}^2 |x_i|^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}$$ and for every $x \in \ell_\infty^2$ the norm is $$||x||_\infty=\max_i |x_i|.$$

Those two definitions don't really help me to prove $\ell _2 ^2$ is not isometric to $\ell _2 ^\infty$.

On the other hand, I have found a theorem for this:

> Every $n$-dimentional normed space $X$ is isomorphic to the Euclidean space $\ell_2^n$. Consequently, all $n$-dimentional normed spaces are isomorphic to each other.

Maybe there is a way to prove those two finite dimensional normed spaces are not isomorphic and then it will follow they are not isometric?

Comment: They are isomorphic. Look at the unit spheres of the spaces, drawn in the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\ell_2^2$ is a norm induced from an inner product it must satisfy the parallelogram law. On the other hand, this law doesn't hold in $\ell_\infty^2$. For example, take $e=(1,0)$ and $f=(1,1)$. Then:

$||e||_\infty^2+||f||_\infty^2=1+1=2$

$\frac{1}{2}(||e+f||_\infty^2+||e-f||_\infty^2)=\frac{1}{2}(2^2+1^2)=\frac{5}{2}$

It follows that there can't be a norm-preserving isomorphism between these two normed spaces.